# Play 2.2.1 java + deadbolt = UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES

Tags: playframework-2.2, deadbolt

I'm trying to install deadbolt on Play 2.2.1 java...
Where is the error? 
I found several threads on the internet talking about this problem, but no answer solved my problem. 
Can anyone help me?

**plugins.sbt**

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
resolvers += Resolver.url("Objectify Play Repository",     url("http://schaloner.github.com/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
resolvers += Resolver.url("Objectify Play Snapshot Repository", url("http://schaloner.github.com/snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % System.getProperty("play.version"))
```

**build.sbt**

```
import play.Project._

name := "computer-database-jpa"

version := "1.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc, 
  javaJpa, 
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "3.6.9.Final",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1100-jdbc4",
  "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.2-RC4"
  )

playJavaSettings
```

**log**

```
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/be/objectify/deadbolt-java_2.10/2.2-RC2/deadbolt-java_2.10-2.2-RC2.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/be/objectify/deadbolt-java_2.10/2.2-RC2/deadbolt-java_2.10-2.2-RC2.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: be.objectify#deadbolt-java_2.10;2.2-RC2: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: be.objectify#deadbolt-    java_2.10;2.2-RC2: not found
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed 27/04/2014 17:14:27
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the "Objectify Play" resolver lines from `plugins.sbt` to `build.sbt`.